# jdbc + mysql + русские буквы

Tags: java, jdbc

Подобный вопрос уже задавался, но пролистав множество ссылок, ответ так и не был найден.
База MySql имеет кодировку utf8, при добавлении в базу через консоль никаких проблем с русскими буквами нет. Однако при попытке добавления русских букв через java добавляются знаки ?. Перед запросом создаю  properties:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("user",username);
    properties.setProperty("password",password);
    properties.setProperty("useUnicode","true");
    properties.setProperty("characterEncoding","UTF-8");
```

Попытка заменить utf8 на cp1251 ни к чему  не привела.
Как же все-таки добавить через java русские буквы?
 Добавление данных черех java:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbAddr +"/"+ dbName, username, password);
    Statement st=c.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("insert into Students values (2, \"Катя\",\"Fkti\",20,\"spb\")");
}
```

Comment: Что именно значит "через java"? Откуда берутся данные добавляемые в базу? Какую исходную кодировку они имеют?

Comment: Данные - обычный String, Через java:                                                                                     
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbAddr +"/"+ dbName,  
             username, password);
        Statement st=c.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("insert into Students values (2, \"Катя\",\"Fkti\",20,\"spb\")");
    }

Comment: Как компилировали?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась:

```
 Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbAddr+"?"+"characterEncoding=utf8", username, password);
    Statement st=c.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("insert into tabl values (\"имя\",20)");
```